# Ejercicio de Multiplicación Sencillo - Bucle while (Java)

Tags: java, while

Gente, buenas tardes, estoy realizando un ejercicio bastante simple (que no puedo resolver), con 2 métodos, donde se pregunta una multiplicación, y de acuerdo a la respuesta (por consola) devuelve el método 'verificarMultiplicar' 'true' o 'false' para continuar con una iteración de 10 multiplicaciones continuas.

El problema que tengo es que cuando ingreso un resultado 'incorrecto' de dicha multiplicación hasta entrar en un 'while' y responder correctamente, el ejercicio se congela, y no continua preguntando por el resto de las multiplicaciones.

Para dichas multiplicaciones, utilizo el método aleatorio 'SecureRandom'.

Es bastante sencillo, pero no me puedo dar cuenta, incluso utilizando el Debugger, la razón por la cual no continua con el bucle de 10 iteraciones.

Me pueden ayudar? Gracias!

```
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InstruccionAsistida {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int contador=0;

        while(contador<10) {

            Multiplicacion objeto=new Multiplicacion();

            int resultadoCorrecto=objeto.resultadoMultiplicar();

            boolean resultadoAlumno=objeto.verificaMultiplicar(resultadoCorrecto);

            while(resultadoAlumno==false) {         

                objeto.verificaMultiplicar(resultadoCorrecto);
            }

            contador++;

            System.out.println("Contador:" + contador);

        }




    }
}

    class Multiplicacion{


        public int resultadoMultiplicar() {

            SecureRandom multiplicacionAleatoria=new SecureRandom();

            int dato1Multiplicacion=1+multiplicacionAleatoria.nextInt(9);

            int dato2Multiplicacion=1+multiplicacionAleatoria.nextInt(9);

            int resultadoFinal=dato1Multiplicacion*dato2Multiplicacion;

            System.out.println("Cuanto es " + dato1Multiplicacion + " X " + dato2Multiplicacion +"?" );

            return resultadoFinal;
        }       


        public boolean verificaMultiplicar(int a) {

            boolean estado=true;

            Scanner entradaAlumno=new Scanner(System.in);

            int respuestaAlumno=entradaAlumno.nextInt();

            if(respuestaAlumno==a) {

                System.out.println("Muy bien!");

                estado=true;

            }

            else {

                System.out.println("No. Por favor intenta de nuevo");

                estado=false;
            }


            return estado;

        }



        }
```

Comment: Parece que te metes en un ciclo infinito al no asignar el valor que te regres verificarMultiplicar a la variable resultadoAlumno,  esto dentro del while anidado: Prueba asignandolo a la variable resultadoAlumno

resultadoAlumno=objeto.verificaMultiplicar(resultadoCorrecto);

Comment: Si Manuel! Ahi lo he solucionado. El problema es que nunca cambiaba el valor de la variable boolean resultadoAlumno. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Ya lo he solucionado! El problema es que no sabia del bucle que comparaba los resultados, y siempre esta en false.

Lo solucione asi:

```
while(resultadoAlumno==false) {         

                if(objeto.verificaMultiplicar(resultadoCorrecto)) {

                    resultadoAlumno=true;
                }

            }
```